# unix java classpath cp adding

Tags: java, linux, classpath

This seemingly simple problem is stumping me. I have a jar with a set of dependencies which I cannot seem to get working in linux. All jars and the script reside in the same directory.

This one picks up and tries to run my main class

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.mylib.MyMainClass
```

but of course it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` on one of the dependency classes. So then I try to add one of the dependencies like so

```
java -cp MyJar.jar:MyDependencyJar.jar com.mylib.MyMainClass
```

Then it says `ClassNotFoundException` for `com.mylib.MyMainClass` !

I also tried these with various same problems

```
java -cp . com.mylib.MyMainClass
```

and this

```
java -cp *.jar com.mylib.MyMainClass
```

and this

```
java -cp .:*.jar com.mylib.MyMainClass
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: If `com.mylib.MyMainClass` is in `MyJar.jar` and all dependency classes in `MyDependencyJar.jar` then `java -cp MyJar.jar:MyDependencyJar.jar com.mylib.MyMainClass` must work. What else is in the current directory?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought and assumed. It stubbornly would not work though. Only putting full path names before each dependency as per the first answer works. I am quite amazed by this but there it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
java -cp /path/to/jar1.jar:/path/to/jar2.jar:. com.mylib.MyMainClass
```

Note that you should not omit that final `.` in the classpath, which represent the current working directory, because using `-cp` would override your previous classpath setting.

Comment: You **can** use a wildcard in the classpath like `java -cp /path/to/*:. com.mylib.MyMainClass`. With that all Jar files in `/path/to/` would be added to the classpath.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes you are right. My fault. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this command in the directory that is the parent of `com/mylib`.  I'm assuming that `MyMainClass.class`, `MyJar.jar`, and `MyDependencyJar.jar` all appear in `com/mylib`.

Try this:

```
java -cp .:MyJar.jar:MyDependencyJar.jar com.mylib.MyMainClass
```